# Association in Mongodb in rails many time fails to find data but sometime works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Here i have Review module

```
class Review
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :job

  has_many :options, :class_name => "Option"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Also Option Model

```
class Option
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps
   field :name, type: String
   field :comment, type: String
   belongs_to :review,:class_name => "Review"
end
```

Now in my Employee:: Review controller

```
  def show
    @employee_review = Employee::Review.find(params[:id])
    @employee = Employee::Employee.find(@employee_review.employee)
    @employee_id = @employee.id
    @job_title = @employee.job.id
    @review = Review.find_by(job_id: @job_title)

  end
```

Here  `@review = Review.find_by(job_id: @job_title)` 
This code rarely works.
I checked out there id passed in @job_title everytime But it does not find the data inside Review model everytime. But when i use Reviews controller to check data then it works automatically in Employee:: Review controller to find that data related to given job_id .
What could be the reason of not finding data in Review model through this controller?
But sometime it finds.

Comment: Can you use .find! and find_by! to see which query doesn't find something?

Comment: I don't get you How can i use that any workin example in my code will be helpful

Comment: replace your .find method calls with .find! 
the difference being that rails will throw an exception when the query doesn't find an entry for your query
    
    Employee::Review.find!(...)

Comment: again same error NameError at /employee/reviews/515a60bb6d7ab86e1a000014
uninitialized constant Employee::ReviewsController::Review

Comment: But when i refresh the related data in reviews controller associated to review Model, then again reload that error page then no error this time it finds and show the related data.

Comment: What's your MongoDB configuration?

Comment: Why are you accessing Review (or is it Employee::Review) sometimes with its namespace and sometimes without it?

Comment: Yes there are two controller and model related review. One is sipmply reviews controller with review model another is  Employee::Reviews controller with  Employee::Review model..   Here in  Employee::Review Controller I want to use Review model hence this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you go the other way around?

`@review = Job.find(@job_title).reviews`

Comment: there is no association among Job model and Review model so this code gives error

Comment: I want to send send Job id in review module by selecting job types. Later on by accesing review model i can do review.job.name.

Comment: Does a Job **has many** reviews or, does a Job **has one** review?

Comment: job has no association with review.. only i have to save job id in review so that i can select job and save its id in review model.. later on i can use review.job.name in show page.